# É possível enviar mensagens de um WebWorker para outro WebWorker?

Tags: javascript, html5, web-worker

Eu tenho uma página onde pretendo utilizar um conjunto de WebWorkers para realizar tarefas em segundo plano. Cada WebWorker tem uma função específica, porém potencialmente útil aos demais. É simples receber/enviar mensagens de/para um WebWorker **criado pela página** (ou criado por um WebWorker específico, no caso de sub-workers), pois existe uma referência para o `Worker` na qual pode-se adicionar ouvintes ou chamar métodos:

```
var worker1 = new Worker("script1.js");
worker1.postMessage("bla");
worker1.onmessage = function(mensagem) {
    alert(mensagem.data);
};

var worker2 = new Worker("script2.js");
...
```

Mas se, digamos, o `script1.js` quiser enviar uma mensagem ao `worker2`, é possível fazê-lo sem "rotear" a mensagem através do *thread* principal? (i.e. o `onmessage` do `worker1` recebe a mensagem e faz um `postMessage` pro `worker2`)

A razão é performance: como o [HTML5 Web Messaging](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/) **serializa** os parâmetros da mensagem (e no momento dessa escrita a maioria dos navegadores ainda não dão suporte a `Transferable`s), esse "roteamento" exigiria que os dados fossem serializados e de-serializados duas vezes, ainda que o *overhead* de se enviar duas mensagens fosse negligível (o que nem sempre é verdade, uma vez que certas aplicações - WebGL por exemplo - podem manter o *thread* principal ocupado por muito tempo).

Comment: Você já investigou o uso das Shared Workers? Eu sei que o suporte a elas está limitado no momento ao Chrome, Safari e Opera, mas você poderia implementar um *shim* para fazer funcionar no Firefox e IE...

Comment: @MarcoAurélio Estou lendo sobre Shared Workers, e parece promissor. Vou tentar criar uma prova de conceito. Só tenho minhas dúvidas se seria possível criar um *shim* que não sofresse dos problemas de performance mencionados acima...

Comment: O shim provavelmente sofreria dos problemas de performance mesmo. :( Mas pelo menos funcionaria. Uma outra coisa se considerar é usar JSON.stringify() e JSON.parse() para fazer a serialização e a deserialização manualmente na worker que envia a mensagem e na worker que recebe ela, dessa forma você economiza as operações de serialização. (Suponho que as strings sejam passadas intactas, já que são imutáveis e podem ser compartilhadas por threads em teoria.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar o *MessageChannel* para comunicar entre os dois *WebWokers*. Estou trabalhando num código de exemplo no [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexandre/J9ynQ/1/), mas você pode ver algo funcional nestes links:

- [Documentação WebPlatform.org](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/web-messaging/MessageChannel)
- [Documentação no MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/apps/hh441303.aspx)
- [Pergunta no Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191394/web-workers-communication-using-messagechannel-html5)
- [Exemplo dado no artigo de cima](http://threadcomm.appspot.com/)

Comment: Excelente! Só não é perfeito porque para usar `MessageChannel` o suporte a `Transferable`s é necessário, mas creio que é o melhor que eu poderia esperar...